# Need to restrict a user from saving a report in Public Reports folder

Tags: reporting, administration

I have a request from upper management saying that no user is allowed to create and save a report in the Public Reports folder. We need to keep that folder tidy.

I gave the user just these permissions on their Profile:

1. Create and Customize Reports
2. Run Reports (dependent)

Every other "report" related permission is UNCHECKED.

Is this possible? If no, is there a workaround?

Related idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kw8AAAQ

Answer (score 1):

I spent a whole day in this and here is the only workaround I found and that I will most likely implement. This workaround was found on the IdeaExchange link you provided.

"This is one of the most frustrating things of my day! Our company mandated (via audit) that we keep the Unfiled Public Reports folder free of any reports as a daily maintenance task. To help combat this I created a report and saved it to to the Unfiled Public Reports folder to serve as a notification to end users NOT to save to this folder (see report details below), the report doesn't include anything but serves only as a warning within the report folder not to save there. Then I setup a report to count the number of reports found in this folder and subscribed to the report to alert me via email to alert me of any reports saved in this folder. This has helped to monitor and move/delete any reports promptly from the Unfiled Public Reports folder. Lastly, I have a report that identifies how many reports that I've had to remove from this folder to-date to show corporate (if ever audited again) that I've been keeping this folder clean of reports. All of this should not be needed if we simply as admins had the means to hide this report folder and stop end users from saving to it. This issue has been open for far too long!

Report Name:
ALERT DO NOT SAVE REPORTS IN THIS FOLDER!

Report Description:
Any reports saved to this folder will be removed promptly due to corporate audit mandate. This folder is not to be used for Report Sharing use, a Demand must accompany any field based report."

Hope this helps!